# After effects colors appear different from Canva - Why?

Tags: adobe, after-effects

I am trying to build a animated video in After effects, I am facing a lot of problems in matching this particular color (#062944).

In canva, it's giving me a different color,

[image: Canva Output]

In after effects, it gives me a different color on a solid composition. What am I missing here?

[image: After effects output]

I am struck on this for over a week now, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.